# Error during installation via command line of MaaS Region Controller

Tags: 14.04, maas

I've tried to install the MaaS Region Controller via stable ppa on an Ubuntu 14.04lts Svr Edition clear, using the following commands as suggested from official guide

> **$: sudo apt-get install maas-region-controller**

but during the installation of the database I've received the following error:

[image]

I've also try to install maas via

> **$: sudo apt-get install maas maas-dns maas-dhcp**

but the error was the same

Why? and is there someone that have tried to install just the Region Controller and a Cluster Controller on a different physical host to create an separate MaaS environment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like you might not have postgresql installed.

Comment: maybe yes, but maas package should install also postgresql when we run it or not?.......because if I've to install first it and then procedure with maas should be presented on the official guide!

Comment: Not arguing that you should have, just pointing out that that looks to be the error.  You might start with setting up both servers on one machine, then, when that works, add a second cluster controller (on another machine) that points back to the region controller, and remove the cluster controller on the region controller server.

Comment: at the end the solution was that, I've installed maas from a clean ubuntu, then added a new cluster. I've not found any solution to realize that using just the single packages

Comment: You should put that as the answer, so the question doesn't sit unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been to install MaaS directly using the ISO and then disable the Cluster Controller from MaaS Ui

[image]

also if this is not what I want to realize but it's a useful solution